# Correct way to design socket connection app in Angular

Tags: angular, socket.io, rxjs

I am writing a sort of chat app in Angular9.
Socket.io server runs in nodeJS and i talk with it using an Angular service.
Actually i have several components (SingleChat/VideoChat/GroupChat) that get and set data from/to the service using RxJS and it runs fine.
The problem is that every component has their own subscriptions and the user cannot receive Video notification while in SingleChat and viceversa.

I think i need to refactor the app moving subscription logic in general app.compoment (putting UI in toolbar, for example); i think this may be the right approach but the problem is: when a message arrives to the Main app.component, how to i inform SingleChat component? Has it to subscribe app.component to receive the message? Is it the right way or is there a bettere way?

```
SOCKET            ANGULAR    subscription TOOLBAR         subscription 
-------------->             <----------->                <---------------> ChatComponent
SERVER            SERVICE     observable  APP.COMPONENT   observable
```

Comment: are you using socket io namespaces for separating those chats https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#Namespaces

Comment: @Xesenix yes, they are in different rooms; but the problem stands in client side development